# linq to sql can't save time (hour, minute) to sql server

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to save Linq to SQL `DateTime` field which has year, month, day, hour, minute, but only year, day, month is getting saved on the server, hour and minute is saved to SQL as `00:00`. The format of the field in the DB is `datetime`, linq to sql is `DateTime`.

My date is well parsed by this code:

```
DateTime tosave = new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, x.Day,x.Hour, x.Minute, x.Second);
```

I receive no errors on `SubmitChanges();`

Comment: If it was date and you changed it to datetime try removing the table from the context file and re-drag it again

Comment: What is the exact type of the database column where you save the `DateTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was date and you changed it to datetime try removing the table from the context file and re-drag it again.

Save and try again

Comment: I just changed Update Check on the scheme of my field from Never to Always and everything saves correctly!
Thanks a lot Issa for the help!